# Typing an acute e when dead keys are eliminated in keyboard layout?

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, xfce

I've disabled dead keys on my Swedish keyboard layout to more easily type characters such as ~,´ and `.

How do I temporarily enable the old behavior of these keys? Now I can't type an e with an acute character, for instance. Do I need to switch keyboard layouts temporarily, or is there some key-combo I am missing out on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>, then *hold down Ctrl+Shift* while typing the Unicode code point of any character, then release Ctrl+Shift to realize it as a character. For example, to type é, this becomes Ctrl+Shift+U+E9 because é is U+00E9 (you don't have to type out the initial zeroes).

This trick works fine with GTK-based applications running under Xfce for me.

If you only need to type *a few different* such characters, this may be acceptable, but I'll be the first to admit that I wouldn't want to commit half of even the Unicode BMP to memory.

Another alternative is to augment the key map to [define a <kbd>Compose</kbd> key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key), as suggested by [ott--](https://superuser.com/users/102019/ott) in the comments. I looked around a little and couldn't immediately find any way to do it through the GUI (from the looks of the Wikipedia article it should be perfectly doable, but I failed to find the dialog in question), but did come across [a forum post](http://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=5995) that suggested using the likes of `setxkbmap -option compose:rwin`, which could quite possibly be done through ~/.xinitrc or ~/.xsession. Then <kbd>Compose</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd> followed by <kbd>E</kbd> (where <kbd>Compose</kbd> = <kbd>Right Win</kbd>) yields `É`.

Comment: Isn't the compose key `Shift AltGr` in Linux?

Comment: Try `Shift AltGr ' e`. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key